# How to change the border color of a full div when on focus?

Tags: javascript, colors, border, onfocus

I'm new to development so this may be a simple answer. I'm trying to figure out how to change the border color of an entire div when in focus/active. I am able to change the text box border but that seems to be the only answers I can find. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your css file..

```
div:focus {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div:active {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can change 'black' to whichever color you prefer.

Comment: Thank you! Do I not need to use on focus in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Version**

```
div:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Javascript Version**

```
//doSomething is the name of the function to get fired
    document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("focus", doSomething);

//whatIsActive will return the element type that is active at the moment
    var whatIsActive = document.activeElement;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_activeelement.asp

Although both are effective, I would only recommend the javascript method if you are changing something other than the physical appearance of the div.

*--- Edit for below comment ---*

**FOCUS**

```
//listens for focus on textbox
document.getElementById('myTextbox').addEventListener("focus", changeDivColor);

//this is fired when the textbox is focused
function changeDivColor(){
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

**BLUR (deselect)**

```
//listens for blur on textbox
 document.getElementById('myTextbox').addEventListener("blur", revertDivColor);

//this is fired when the textbox is no longer focused
function revertDivColor(){
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.borderColor = "black";
}
```

**SEE IT IN ACTION:** https://jsfiddle.net/0h8zyhba/1/

Comment: Thank you! This is almost what I'm looking for. Any help on how to keep the Div border on the changed color once you've clicked on a text box within the Div and then change to the default color once click on a different Div?

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for but I can't get it to work in my browser. I'll keep playing around with it!

Comment: What browser are you using? Safari, Firefox, and Chrome all worked for me. Did you check out the JSFiddle above?